# Ninject Dependency Injection for SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, signalr

In my `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file, under `CreateKernel` method I am applying the injection like this

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);

        // Web API Injection
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);                     

        // SignalR Injection
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new SignalR.Ninject.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

        return kernel;
    }
```

I was thinking that should do it for me but i keep getting an error at the SignalR injection that

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'SignalR.Ninject.NinjectDependencyResolver' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver'"

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I'm not sure if the two are compatible, but you could attempt to typecast the dependency resolver to `(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver)` when you perform the assignment.

Comment: It does remove the error, but the ninject dependency injection doesnt work. From the posts i have seen, this typecasting should never have been necessary in the first place.....dunno what the problem is

Comment: Are you sure that your `NinjectDependencyResolver` inherits from `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver`? Can you paste the code?

Comment: I am not familiar with SignalR at all, you are using an "I"nterface on one side of the cast, but a "real object" on the other.  Is there an "I"NinjectDependencyResolver?

Comment: @AlexG SignalR.Ninject.NinjectDependencyResolver is being provided by SignalR.Ninject library, so am just using that. And yes, it inherits from DefaultDependencyResolver which in turn inherits from IDependencyResolver

Comment: @JcMaltaDev isnt that the purpose of Dependency injection? using interfaces as real objects

Comment: In that case my only suggestion is to check that you are using compatible versions of each library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if you have found the answer or not.  They have changed the way DI works in SignalR as of version 1.0.0 and the SignalR.Ninject packages doesn't work - I have written a small blog post on this: http://myrandomcodesnippets.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/ninject-dependency-injection-with-signalr-1-0-1/

Basically you need to create your own implementation of this which is the same as the SignalR.Ninject implementation:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new SignalRNinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
```

When you create the new class it will want to inherit from IDependancyResolver don't bother with this and use:

```
public class SignalRNinjectDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public SignalRNinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.TryGet(serviceType) ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType).Concat(base.GetServices(serviceType));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: SignalRNinjectDependencyResolver good, but its not enough for using Modules in the solution. PLease make update ?

Comment: SignalR has moved on a lot since I wrote this.  You may want to look at how you can implement SignalR with Owin/Post a question with your problem.