# SignalR with Ninject has stopped injecting hub dependencies

Tags: c#, ninject, signalr

Using the responses to other questions here on SO, I managed to get dependency injection working with SignalR using Ninject. But it's in a piece of my code that I was ignoring for a while, and after several weeks I'm back looking at it - and it appears to have stopped working, and I can't seem to figure out why.

I'm creating my Ninject kernel appropriately:

```
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        Kernel = kernel;
        return kernel;
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
        kernel.Bind<ISessionWrapper>().To<SessionWrapper>();

        kernel.Bind<IPayboardEntities>().To<PayboardEntities>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationService>().To<AuthenticationService>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IAuthorizationService>().To<AuthorizationService>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<ITokenService>().To<TokenService>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<fsIntegrations.RealtimeService>().To<fsIntegrations.RealtimeService>().InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<IDataServiceFactory>()
            .To<fsIntegrations.DataServiceFactory>()
            .InSingletonScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument("kernel", kernel);

        kernel.Bind<IntegrationHub>().To<IntegrationHub>();
        kernel.Bind<CustomerHub>().To<CustomerHub>();
    }
```

I'm overriding the SignalR DependencyResolver in Global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        // To support Ninject with SignalR
        // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706530/ninject-dependency-injection-for-signalr
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new SignalRNinjectDependencyResolver(NinjectWebCommon.Kernel);

        // Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); 

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        BootstrapBundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        SimpleSocialAuthBundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

But when SignalR tries to create any of my hubs (I'm using constructor injection), it throws this exception:

`System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

This used to work, and I don't *think* I've changed anything that would have broken it - though obviously something did.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh. Turns out I do this sort of thing too often. It was a stupid mistake on my part - though I do wish that there had been a better error message. Turns out that I hadn't registered with Ninject a class depended on by one of the classes depended on by one of the classes depended on by my hub. (Got that?)